# DomPDF Zend not executing PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, execute, dompdf

This is my controller function that actually does not generate the right PDF for my problem.

This only generate the static HTML PDF but my requirement is create PDF on dynamic created HTML.

```
$archive_msgs = $this->getRequest()->getPost('ids');
    $archive_ids = explode(",",$archive_msgs);
    $ul = '<ul>';
    if(!empty($archive_ids)){
        foreach($archive_ids as $archive){
            if(trim($archive)!=''){ 
                $msgdata = $this->getQuerydataWithPrimary('message', 'msgID', $archive);
                $dec_data = base64_decode($msgdata[0]['message']['S']);
                $arr_data_com = explode(",,", $dec_data);
                $arr_temp = implode("",$arr_data_com);
                $arr_data_dash = explode("--", $arr_temp);

                for($j=1; $j<sizeof($arr_data_dash); $j+=3)
                {
                    $ul .="<li>".$arr_data_dash[$j].":".$arr_data_dash[$j+1]."</li>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $ul .= '</ul>';
$genhtml = '
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:WX="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

   </head>
   <body id="body1">
<script type="text/php"> 
echo $ul;
</script>           

   </body>
</html> '; 

$dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
$source = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pem/Source_page.phtml';   

file_put_contents($source, $genhtml);
$html = file_get_contents($source);
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_option('enable_remote', TRUE);
$dompdf->set_option('enable_css_float', TRUE);
$dompdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', FALSE);

$dompdf->render();

$date = date('Y-m-d');
$dompdf->stream("CS_Message_".$date.".pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v0.6.1 dompdf removed PHP-preprocessing (e.g. `eval`ing any `<?php ... ?>`).

As of v0.6.x dompdf stopped processing inline script (`<script type="text/php"></script>`) by default; you have to enable that functionality in the configuration. Look for the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` setting or use `$dompdf->set_option('enable_php', true)`.

All that being said, you're doing it wrong. You can't `echo` content into the HTML document that you feed to dompdf. dompdf does not capture the content of inline script and feed it back into the document. This function is essentially a way to access the PDF backend during document parsing. You need to put together your document prior to feeding it to dompdf.

You do not really need to save the file in order to load it into dompdf (unless you are doing that to cache the page). Something like the following should work:

```
// preceding code intentionally left out
$genhtml = '
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:WX="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body id="body1">
      ' . $ul . '
   </body>
</html> '; 

$dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($genhtml);
$dompdf->set_option('enable_remote', TRUE);
$dompdf->set_option('enable_css_float', TRUE);
$dompdf->set_option('enable_html5_parser', FALSE);

$dompdf->render();

$date = date('Y-m-d');
$dompdf->stream("CS_Message_".$date.".pdf");
```